# Define range referring to a certain value.(.find method)

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to define a range to import date in the range by referring to a certain value.

The data(kind of DB) is already sorted by pre-steps of my macro. 
So, I tried to find the first row and the last row to define the range.

but the result for the last row shows the same row of the first row.

This is my row counting.

```
First targetRow::1743 
1744 
1745 
1746 
1747 
1748 
1749 
1750 
1751 
1752 
1753 
1754 
1755 
1756 
1757 
1758 
1759 
1760 
1761 
1762 
1763 
1764 
1765 
1766 
1767 
1768 
1769 
1770 
1771 
1772 
1773 
1774 
1743 
Last targetRow ::1743
```

''''  Form = main workbook and DB = DB workbook.

```
With DB.Sheets("rig_line").Range("b1:b" & lastRow)
    Set field = .Find(Form.Sheets("Forklift RQST").Range("rig_id"), lookat:=xlWhole)

    If field Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No value!!!"
    Else
        targetRow = field.Row
        Debug.Print "First targetRow::" & targetRow
        Do
            Set field = .FindNext(field)
            lastRow = field.Row

            Debug.Print lastRow

            If field.Row = targetRow Then Exit Do
        Loop While Not field Is Nothing
    End If

End With

Debug.Print "first Row ::" & targetRow
Debug.Print "last Row ::" & lastRow
```

I want to get the last row values as 1774.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues here:

1. You are using `lastRow` to initialise the search range.  Unless it's been previously set in code not shown, this will be a problem.  I've assumed you want to search all data in Column `B`
2. Some parameters of `.Find` must be explicitly set each time you call it, or you may get unexpected results
   See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144128)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue), specifically

   > The settings for LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method.
   >   If you do not specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method (either by VBA or the user), the saved values are used.
3. You need to start the search after the last cell in `SearchRange`, to avoid missing a find in the first cell of the range
4. You need to test if `targetRow` is found again before updating `lastRow`
5. The `Do ... Loop` will always be exited by the `If ... Then Exit Do` so the `While` clause is redundant.

```
Dim SearchRange As Range
With Db.Sheets("rig_line")
    Set SearchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))

    Set field = SearchRange.Find( _
      After:=SearchRange.Cells(SearchRange.Count), _
      What:=Form.Sheets("Forklift RQST").Range("rig_id").Value, _
      LookIn:=xlValues, _
      Lookat:=xlWhole, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)

    lastRow = 0
    If field Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No value!!!"
    Else
        targetRow = field.Row
        Debug.Print "First targetRow::" & targetRow
        Do
            Set field = .FindNext(field)
            If field.Row = targetRow Then Exit Do
            lastRow = field.Row

            Debug.Print "lastRow::" & lastRow
        Loop 
    End If
End With

Debug.Print "first Row ::" & targetRow
Debug.Print "last Row ::" & lastRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate your help! I could solve the issue by adding `After:=` line.